# Keypad schematic - is it correct?

Tags: microcontroller, diodes, switches, keypad

What do you think of this schematic for my Arduino keypad? Are the diodes pointing the right way?

I will make `col1` "high" and then check pins `row1`, `row2`, `row3` and `row4` and see if current is flowing through. Then make `col2` and `col3` "high" and again check if current is flowing through the row pins.

[image: My Schematic:]

Update:

Ok so I´ll change the direction of the diodes. In my code I will declare my rows as inputs and my columns as outputs. Then I will set all columns to "HIGH". To check which keys are pressed I will set col1 to low. There should be current flowing if any key in that column is pressed. I will then check my rows if their state has changed to "LOW". I will repeat the process for col2 and col3. The anti-ghosting diodes should still work. This way it could work right?

Comment: Consider using Schottky diodes instead of 1N4148, for better margins. Then your inputs will be at ~4.8V instead of ~4.3V. This in turn gives better tolerance for temperature variations, inaccurate supply voltage etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the diodes are that way, then columns should be inputs with pull-ups enabled, and rows should be outputs, the scanned row being low, and the other rows high.

If you want columns to be outputs, and rows as inputs, then the diodes are the wrong way around.

Comment: Ok thank you. So do diodes show the way of "real" current/electrons flowing?

Comment: no, diodes show the way of conventional current.

Comment: But then my schematic should be fine, right? As far as I know putting a pin to high makes it +5V. So the conventional current will flow from col1 through the diodes and into the rows... I would use internal pulldown resistors on my row pins.

Comment: with some reservation about speed of operation, this looks ok.

Comment: ok. But if i use pull-up resistors on my rows. Then I would need to have my columns on "high" and then put them to "low" if I want to check if the key is pressed right? I wouldhave to change the directions of the diodes then I think.

Comment: You can't use internal pull-downs on Arduino, because it does not have any. It only has internal pull-ups, so that's why I said rows must be outputs, and colums must be inputs with internal pull-up enabled, so that the schematic is correct and you don't need external components. A low output on row, would make column low via diode when button is pressed, if column is an input with internal pull-up

Answer (score 0):

you can replace  diodes for each switch with one diode on the main row end `rowN`. Otherwise it looks ok to me with the way you have described.

Comment: Ok thanks. But I want to use those diodes for anti-ghosting so I think there should be one diode for every pin.

Comment: That is right, each button needs a diode of it's own to prevent ghosting.